# how to get the data using pycassa with uuid key

Tags: python, get, cassandra, uuid, pycassa

I inserted the data like this.

```
import pycassa, datetime
cf.insert(pycassa.util.convert_time_to_uuid(datetime.datetime.now()),{str(i): 'val'})
```

......

### data

```
dbed33be-cc9e-11e1-8080-808080808080 OrderedDict([('column1', 'val1')])
```

How to get the data with uuid key?

I tried to get the data like this.

```
cf.get("UUID('dbed33be-cc9e-11e1-8080-808080808080')")
cf.get("dbed33be-cc9e-11e1-8080-808080808080")
cf.get(UUID('dbed33be-cc9e-11e1-8080-808080808080'))
```

But, I didn't get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close to the solution, but yet so far away..

---

[`pycassa.util.convert_time_to_uuid`](http://pycassa.github.com/pycassa/api/pycassa/util.html) will return a value of type `uuid.UUID`, to generate one from a string (as you've tried) you will need to use either of the below methods:

```py
UUID('{12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678}')

UUID('12345678123456781234567812345678')

UUID('urn:uuid:12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678')
```

```
cf.get(UUID('{dbed33be-cc9e-11e1-8080-808080808080}')) # example
```

---

Read more about `UUID` under the following link:

- **[20.15. uuid — UUID objects according to RFC 4122 — Python v2.7.3 documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html)**